# How to make a website from .pdf / .ai / .svg files?

Tags: web-development, website-design, pdf, svg

I have designed an infographic for a client using Illustrator and now they asked me to make a website for them based on the infographic.

I use Adobe Dreamweaver occasionally, but I'm not good with it, I might sound like a newbie but Notepad++ was usually enough for my needs, and I'm not sure how should I position all those different images and texts so they look just like the infographic.

Now I am looking for an easy way to convert my PDF designs to a website, without having to learn how to position all those images and texts together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never find an application that does the job perfectly but their are some [PDF to HTML convertors online](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pdf%20to%20html) that can convert simple to fairly complex PDF designs.

The other option would be to pay a designer to take the PDF design and make it into a friendly HTML design that works as intended, AI/PDF/SVG > HTML convertors are not perfect and sometimes are not successful while a designer would or should do it justice.

Finally you could always ask your client to embed the PDF file onto the website meaning the PDF is served in a frame, there are lots different ways you can [embed the PDF on their website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html).

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look for some kind of [PDF to HTML converter](https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+to+html+converter&oq=pdf+to+HTML+co&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and perhaps [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103312/is-there-any-flawless-pdf-to-html-converter) might help?

However, I have not tried something like this myself and I would be very sceptical as to the quality of the HTML/CSS produced. An automated tool might be able to make it *look* acceptable, but there is a lot more to creating a web page than simply how it looks. Accessibility, semantic markup and SEO for instance. The ability to be able to update the page in the future might also be a concern. An automated tool is likely to generate a bloated page (large size, slow and more bandwidth) that is nothing short of a nightmare to update.

So, basically, you might be able to "get the job done" by using an automated tool, but a proper solution would involve getting your hands dirty with the correct HTML/CSS.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. embedding the PDF is not an option, it is also possible to export from Illustrator to an HTML5 canvas element, but that's not SEO friendly. I think I should start learning or pay someone to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the PDF in a webpage, on a test website, and ask them if that works for them. Maybe put header and footer. Tell them that is the cheapest way.